# Dynamic path in new.AjaxRequest with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototypejs

I was wondering if there's anyway to get a 'dynamic path' into a .js file through Ruby on Rails.

For example, I have the following:

```
new Ajax.Request('/tokens/destroy/' + GRID_ID, {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, onComplete:function(request){load('26', 'table1', request.responseText)}, parameters:'token=' + dsrc.id + '&authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent(AUTH_TOKEN)})
```

The main URL is '/tokens/destroy/:id', however on my production server this app runs as a sub folder. So the URL for this ajax call needs to be '/qrpsdrail/tokens/destroy/:id'

The URL this is being called from would be
/grids/1 or /qrpsdrail/grids/1

I could, of course, do ../../path -- but that seems a bit hackish. It is also dependent on the routing never changing, which at this stage I can't guarantee.
I'm just interested in seeing what other solutions there might be to this problem.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a bit hackish solution, but i have a configuration-file like described [here](http://kpumuk.info/ruby-on-rails/flexible-application-configuration-in-ruby-on-rails/), and so you could do something like, inside a `config.yml` :

```
development:
  root: /

production:
  root: /qrpsdrail/
```

and when you build your Ajaxrequest, you could write

```
new Ajax.Request("#{AppConfig.root}tokens/destroy/' + ...
```

But it still looks like there should be a cleaner way to solve this ;)

Comment: I kinda did something similar to this, but yeah I still think it's "hackish" ... I just set var ROOT_PATH = #{root_path} at the top of the template and can use it in the static grid.js library.

I'm looking into perhaps using a javascript template (rjs?) ... but from what I've read that doesn't get cached like a .js file does.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Dynamic path in new.AjaxRequest using javascript in rails

javascript

```
 function dynamic_ajax(GRID_ID)
  {
      new Ajax.Request("/tokens/destroy?"+GRID_ID, {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, onComplete:function(request){load('26', 'table1', request.responseText)}, parameters:'token=' + dsrc.id + '&authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent(AUTH_TOKEN)});
  }
```

html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="dynamic_ajax('1')">Grid Id 1 </a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="dynamic_ajax('2')">Grid Id 2 </a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="dynamic_ajax('3')">Grid Id 3 </a>
```

Comment: The problem is not the GRID_ID that is a constant that I actually initialize elsewhere in the application - the problem is the URL that Ajax.Request calls - it doesn't work on both my environments because it calls absolute paths. Sorry if the question was ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the path as an attribute to your html object that initiates the ajax call.  An example would be:

HTML

```
<a id='my_clicky_thing' href='#' rails_path='<%= tokens_destroy_path %>'>Click me</a>
```

JQuery

```
$('#my_clicky_thing').live('click', function(){
  var ajax_path = $(this).attr('rails_path');
  /* Do ajax stuff here with the path */
});
```

This would allow you to use the actual rails path in your .js files, as you do in your views.

(This code may not work, it is for the concept only)